# Creating a Separate Detail View Page in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

OK, so I've created a form that has 2 connecting drop down list.  I have a button that redirects to another page.  This one is currently blank, but I've tried adding a detail view to it, however, when I try and connect it to the data source it just shows the first of the column names and abc.

I need to know how to connect it to my data source which would create 4 rows and the corresponding information for those rows.  In this case it would be something akin to Quantity, Category, Product Name, and the Description for the item selected on the first page.

Any help is seriously appreciated.

UPDATE

I still can't get this working.

Here is a screenshot of page one.[image]

My instructions for this page are simply...

On the first screen, a user chooses a category and then chooses a product from the selected category. The Category and Product controls are populated using the following procedures: So I set up both of these with the respective procedures, and they work fine.

The order detail button simply redirects to the order detail page, but I'm not sure if I have to do anything to save the selection.

However, here is the code I've put together for those 3 buttons.

```
<div style="height: 182px">
Category: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory"
runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryName"     

DataValueField="CategoryId" AutoPostBack="True"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  
ConnectionStrings:DeveloperInterviewConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="CategoryListing" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">    
</asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br/>

Product: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct"
runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ProductName"   

DataValueField="ProductId"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 

ConnectionStrings:DeveloperInterviewConnectionString %>"  
SelectCommand="CategoryProducts" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory" Name="CategoryId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

<input type="button" value="Order Details"
 onClick="location.href = 'OrderDetails.aspx';">
```

So do I have to do anything to setup the data to go from one form to the next, and I still can't get the view operational.

Comment: are you asking how to pass the parameters from the first page to the second? Can you post some code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  

What I have to do is take the 2 pulldowns which are set to 2 different procedures.

As in the first pulldown is set to Category and pulls data from the Category Listing procedure.  The second pulldown offers up the item name based on the selected category.

Those work fine.  I created an "Order Details" button that directs to a new page, which is supposed to pull the data for the selected item using the ProductDetail procedure. I have not touched asp.net since graduating, and though a details view dragged on the page, and set to the datasouce would do.  it didn't.

Comment: The only code I currently have is associated with the first page, and it's respective buttons.

Comment: whats in the stored proc for the seconds page? Are you returning all the columns you need?

Comment: It won't let me post it.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductDetails]
    ProductId INT ,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT ,
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT ,
    @QuantityInStock INT OUTPUT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON ;

 -- Get Product Details
    SELECT  ProductName = p.ProductName ,
            ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription ,
            QuantityInStock = p.QuantityInStock
    FROM    Product p
    WHERE   p.ProductId = ProductId

Comment: I had to remove at symbols from the code to get it posted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I tried linking up your stored proc to a details view and didn't get very far with it. I think the problem is the output params.

Try modifying the stored proc to the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductDetails]
@ProductId INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
ProductName,
ProductDescription,
QuantityInStock

from Product
where productid = @ProductId

END

GO
```

Point the datasource at that Sproc, link up the ProductID param and you should be set.

UPDATE: adding my asp.net code

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="ProductDescription" SortExpression="ProductDescription" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityInStock" HeaderText="QuantityInStock" SortExpression="QuantityInStock" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DemoDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="ProductDetails" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="ProductId" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I'm still at a loss.  I set up the detail view, made these changes.  I get to the end and it says multiple params were found in my select statement, and to set their values.  For the pulldowns before I went to Control and then selected the associated control value.  If I do that here only CategoryName comes up with the value abc in the next column.

Comment: Updated my answer with my detailsview code. My best guess is you didn't modify the params on the stored proc. Try deleting the grid and starting again with a new datasource.

Comment: I'm still trying, but can't get it I updated the original message to reflect changes.